# Web scraping data and merged with data

Tags: r, rvest

I want to grab data from wikipedia on population for countries and merge it to my data. But the table I webscrape returns an empty list. Below is my full code , only part d of the code isn't working. I need assistance grabbing the data on population and merging it with my total_cases data.

```
#loading tidyverse package
library(tidyverse)
tb_data <- tidyr::who
tb_data

#Part a

#Pivoting all the columns from new_sp_ms014 to newrel_f65
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)

tb_datap <- tb_data %>% pivot_longer(cols = new_sp_m014:newrel_f65,
               names_to = "name",
               values_to = "cases", values_drop_na = TRUE)
tb_datap

#Part b

# Split the name column into three columns
tb_datap <- cbind(
  tb_datap[, 1:4],
  data.frame(
    type = substr(tb_datap$name, 5, 6),
    sex = substr(tb_datap$name, 8, 8),
    age = substr(tb_datap$name, 9, 11),
    cases = tb_datap$cases,
    key = tb_datap$name
  )
)

tb_datap$name <- NULL #removing the column name

tb_datap <- as.tibble(tb_datap) #transforming back to a tibble
tb_datap

#Part c

# Group by country and year, summarize to get the total cases
total_cases <- tb_datap %>%
  group_by(country, year) %>%
  summarize(total_cases = sum(cases))
total_cases

#Part d
library(rvest)

# URL of the Wikipedia page containing the population data
url <- "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_population_(United_Nations)"

# Use rvest to scrape the population table from the page
population_table <- url %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_nodes('.jquery-tablesorter td') %>%
  html_table()
population_table

# Extract the country and population data from the table
population_data <- population_table %>%
  select(2, 4:ncol(population_table)) %>%
  slice(-1) %>%
  pivot_longer(-Country, names_to = "Year", values_to = "Population") %>%
  mutate(Year = as.numeric(str_remove(Year, "\\D+")))

# Merge the population data with the original data frame
merged_data <- total_cases %>%
  left_join(population_data, by = c("Country", "Year"))

# View the merged data frame
merged_data
```

Answer (score 0):

To read the first table on the page this works:

```
library(magrittr)
library(rvest)

url <- "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_population_(United_Nations)"  
page <- read_html(url)

# Use rvest to scrape the population table from the page
population_table <- page %>% html_element("table")
# convert to data frame
population_table <- population_table %>% html_table()

# A tibble: 237 × 6
   `Country / Area` `UN continentalregion[4]` `UN statisticalsubregion[4]` `Population(1 July 2022)` `Population(1 July 2023)` Change
   <chr>            <chr>                     <chr>                        <chr>                     <chr>                     <chr> 
 1 China[a]         Asia                      Eastern Asia                 1,425,887,337             1,425,671,352             −0.02%
 2 India            Asia                      Southern Asia                1,417,173,173             1,428,627,663             +0.81%
 3 United States    Americas                  Northern America             338,289,857               339,996,564               +0.50%
 4 Indonesia        Asia                      South-eastern Asia           275,501,339               277,534,123               +0.74%
 5 Pakistan         Asia                      Southern Asia                235,824,863               240,485,658               +1.98%
```

Comment: When I try to use the select function, it does not work since the output population_table is not a dataframe. Below is the error. Kindly assist.  Error in UseMethod("select") : 
  no applicable method for 'select' applied to an object of class "xml_node"

Comment: @khali-blinks, see edits.  I corrected by adding the reassignment: `population_table <- population_table %>% html_table()`